# Background Position not Animating - jQuery

Tags: jquery, background

Hey Folks I have a little issue today. I am trying to create an animated Menu but its just not working. Any got any clue?

Below is the issue.

jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ul li").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "50% 100%"});
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "50% -100px"});
    });

});
```

CSS Code

```
background-color:transparent;
background-image:url(../images/menu_sel.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:50% -100px;
```

HTML Code

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

I even tried mouseover in jQuery but no go :(

```
$("ul li")      
.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "50% 100%"});
})
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "50% -100px"});
})
```

I also tried simple CSS replacement and it works... but not the animation :(

```
$("ul li")      
.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: "50% 100%"});
})
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: "50% -100px"});
})
```

I cannot get it to work... any clues??

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for us to try?

Comment: Tried not mixing the px and % values? Mayve you're suffering from [the firefox bug described here](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/)? If not, please make a jsfiddle so we can do a more in dept analysis.

Comment: yes, seems like a firefox bug while mixing % and px values... intelligent suggestion... cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

As suggested by all here, jQuery does not handle complex positioning. So below is what finally worked!!

```
.mouseover(function(){
$(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "50% 0"}, {duration:200});
})
.mouseout(function(){
$(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "50% -54px"}, {duration:200});
})
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

jQuery cannot animate complex css values.. it's the same reason you can't do something like:

```
$('#thing').animate({margin: "10px 0 0 10px"});
```

You'll have to animate the individual properties, such as:

```
$('#thing').animate({backgroundPositionX: "50%", backgroundPositionY: "-100px"});
```

Comment: Ah, I apologize but I mean it did not work for me, your suggestion was great!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that jQuery does not support animation two values at once, try:

```
$(this).animate({backgroundPositionY:-100});
```